# Error when separating android project from React Native: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'Require stack:-/home/usr/react_demo/android/[eval]

Tags: android, react-native

I`ve created a standard React Native project with the following structure:
[image]

And I`m trying to seperate the Android project, like this:
[image]

The images were taken from the tutorial I followed: [Separate your Android of React Native](https://developers.ascendcorp.com/integrate-react-native-into-an-existing-android-project-with-separated-repositories-b445c09e0d10).
I changed all the paths in the android project successfully:
**settings.gradle**:

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "AccessApp"
apply from: file("../AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
//                ^^Modified
```

**build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "/home/sharon/react_demo/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url("/home/sharon/react_demo/AwesomeProject/node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle:app**

```
apply from: file("/home/sharon/react_demo/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Also, I`ve changed the path in React Native by creating react-native.config.js in root folder:

**react-native.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
      android: {
        sourceDir: '../android',
      },
    },
  };
```

And then I ran: `npx react-native config`
Unfortunately the project throws an error when building. Full error:

```
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, -e, console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/sharon/react_demo/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 213

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'Require stack:- /home/sharon/react_demo/android/[eval]    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)    at [eval]:1:13    at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:305:38)    at node:internal/process/execution:75:19    at [eval]-wrapper:6:22    at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:74:60) {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: [ '/home/sharon/react_demo/android/[eval]' ]}Node.js v17.3.0
```

Already tried: 1.Deleting node_modules and running `npm install`, 2. running `npm i react-native-cli`
Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @shubhamjha No. I decided to load the bundle separately through the device`s internal storage. In that way I can develop both projects on different machines,

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1600
here is the solution
You need to change /@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).